# Detecting sinusoidal noise

Tags: python, signals, noise, periodic

I have spectroscopic signals that are disturbed by a pseudo-periodic signal. This disturbance is due to a bad positioning of the sensor and this one will badly integrate the number of photons it detects. Of course we could act on the positioning of the sensor, but it is mechanical, so this disturbance may still exist.
So I would like to find a way to detect if there is noise or not. And have a way to model it to correct it. Can you help me ? I work with Python.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKrhp.jpg)

I tried to detect the peaks, but it is not robust enough as there may be peaks that are not noise.

Comment: It's hard to say if signial is noise or true values based on peaks. You should set a threshold based on input data from sender side & then classify based on that thresholds

Comment: Is it fair to assume that the noise is high-frequency compared to any periods in the underlying data?

Comment: Yes, it's more of a interference that is added to the signal. But a "normal" signal should not contain this disturbance.

Comment: What is the frequency of your signal. Is it fixed or variable? Same question for the noise. Is your signal recorded or live?

Comment: This is a spectroscopic signal (counting photons at certain wavelengths), so the signal frequency is variable because we record the absorption of chemical compounds.
The frequency of the noise seems to increase at a constant step.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some new signals. We see that the period and the amplitude increase.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2aHZ.jpg

Comment: What are the units of your axes? Can you provide a file with typical data points; I would like to experiment?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).